# SSRS 2016 executionlog reportID

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

We have multiple reports, each reports use multiples datasource, each report has an itemID, path, type in the catalog.

My question is why every lines in the executionlog has the same reportID which is referenced in the catalog with empty Path and empty Name and null ParentID and Type 1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
The log problem is solved with the installation of this update :  SQLServer2016SP1-KB3182545-x64-FRA.exe
After the installation of this update we got new lines in the log [ExecutionLog3] with ItemAction=RenderMobileReport   (that we did not have before)

Comment: Good to know, thanks for sharing

Answer (score 1):

The log problem is solved with the installation of this update :  SQLServer2016SP1-KB3182545-x64-FRA.exe

After the installation of this update we got new lines in the log [ExecutionLog3] with ItemAction=RenderMobileReport   (that we did not have before)